# Is Perl optimized to skip remaining logic operands if the answer is already decided?

Tags: perl, optimization, logic

For instance, I need to match some text if `$do eq 'b'`.
If I run this code:

```
if (($do eq 'b') && (/text/))
{
do stuff
}
```

Would perl evaluate the first parenthesis and second parenthesis no matter what or would it stop at the evaluation of the second parenthesis if the first parenthesis was false?

Follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178629/in-perl-can-a-short-circuit-evaluation-be-disabled-if-needed). (I didn't know if I should make a new question or post it here)

Comment: The keyword to search for is "short circuit evaluation".

Comment: That's not an optimization, it's quite important behavior.

Comment: @AJMansfield knew it was called somehow but I just couldn't remember. Thanks for bringing it back to me. :)

Comment: @delnan I understant that now. :)

Comment: It's not specific to Perl, [all common programming language have it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in perhaps slightly varied forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  This behavior is commonly used in idiomatic perl.

Consider:

```
open FILE, ">$fname" or die $!;
```

If there is no error opening the file (`open` returns true), the `die` statement is not executed.  This is not special treatment of the `die` routine; it is just the way perl handles logic evaluation.

Comment: Wow, that's so cool, I never would've guessed that this is the logic behind the `or die` statements that I've been using all this time... Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that, Mr. Shafer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Perl short circuits logical operators. This means they can be used for control flow:

```
say "foo" if $bar;
```

is the same as

```
$bar and say "foo";
```

and

```
if ($cond) { stuff() }
```

is the same as

```
$cond and do { stuff() }
```

However, the whole condition of an `if` has to be wrapped in parens, making your example

```
if ($do eq 'b' && /text/) {
  do stuff;
}
```

(`&&` is the same as `and`, but has higher precedence)

Comment: since it wasn't actually the point of question, I fixed the syntax in the question

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: it stops ("short circuits" as AJ points out). You can get a ton more detail [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This behavior is called short-circuiting in the [perlop documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And) (emphasis added).

> #### C-style Logical And
>
> Binary `&&` performs a **short-circuit** logical AND operation. That is, if the left operand is false, the right operand is not even evaluated. Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated.
>
> #### C-style Logical Or
>
> Binary `||` performs a **short-circuit** logical OR operation. That is, if the left operand is true, the right operand is not even evaluated. Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated.

In addition to `&&` and `||` their lower-precedence cousins `and` and `or` also short-circuit.

Perl has an `xor` operator, but it cannot short-circuit due to the definition of [exclusive-or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Answer (score 2):

It would be

```
if ($do eq 'b' && /text/) {
    do stuff
}
```

Yes - if `$do eq 'b'` is false, `/text/` won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

No, right part of condition is not evaluated when left part is `false`,

```
if ($do eq 'b' && /text/)
{
do stuff
}
```

Comment: I know what you *mean*, but the short circuiting you described matches `or`. In contrast, `and` short circuits when the first operand is false.