# In Perl - can a short circuit evaluation be disabled if needed?

Tags: perl, optimization, logic

This is a follow-up question for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178223/is-perl-optimized-to-skip-remaining-logic-operands-if-the-answer-is-already-deci).

For example, let's say I have three procedures that I need to run no matter what and exit if all of them return 1.

```
while (&proc1 && &proc2 && &proc3);
```

Because Perl is using short-circuit evaluation, the code may or may not execute subs &proc2 and &proc3 depending on preceding operands (if an operand is false the following operands won't be executed; more info [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355) and [on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). If needed, is there any way to turn the feature off?

Comment: Please describe your full question here so this will be useful for others.

Comment: don't ever call subroutines with `&` but without `()` unless you know and want the special behaviour that triggers.

Comment: @ysth Please explain the "special behaviour" or provide a link for future reading.

Comment: @AnandWu, `&func` is equivalent to calling `func(@_)`, not `func()`, so it's not safe (Reference: near the end of [Description section of perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the multiplication operator

```
while (&proc1 * &proc2 * &proc3) { ... }
```

This will evaluate all three operands and evaluate to false if any one of them is false (zero).

If you are worried about warnings about uninitialized values, you can use bitwise-and with the `!!` cast-to-boolean pseudo-operator:

```
while (!!&proc1 & !!&proc2 & !!&proc3) { ... }
```

which will do pretty much the same thing. The cast-to-boolean is necessary because the result of a bitwise-and of two arbitrary true values may still be false (e.g., `1 & 2` evaluates to `0`).

Comment: That relies on the true/false values returned by the subroutines being `1`/`0`. They could just as easily be `{}`/`undef`.

Comment: the `!!` solution returns the right value. another solution would be `until( proc1() | proc2() | proc3() )`. And yes, I tested: `perl -E 'say for !({}|{}), !({}|undef), !(undef|undef)'` says nothing, nothing, and 1.

Comment: The answer is completely correct, but I'm afraid it's one of those cases where your maintenance programmer will hate you.

Answer (score 8):

You could just evaluate every clause to temporary variables, then evaluate the entire expression. For example, to avoid short-circuit evaluation in:

```
if ($x < 10 and $y < 100) { do_something(); }
```

write:

```
$first_requirement = ($x < 10);
$second_requirement = ($y < 100);
if ($first_requirement and $second_requirement) { do_something(); }
```

Both conditionals will be evaluated. Presumably, you want more complex conditions with side effects, otherwise there's no reason to evaluate the second condition if the first is false.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I chose mob's answer as the accepted answer because imho it's a bit more "perl-centric".

Comment: I don't see anything not perl-centric about this. If anything it's clearer.

Answer (score 5):

You could write

```
until ( grep !$_, proc1(), proc2(), proc3() ) {
  ...
}
```

Whatever you do, you shouldn't call subroutines using the ampersand syntax, like `&proc1`. That has been wrong for many years, replaced by `proc1()`

Comment: if all the functions return true, grep returns an empty array, which evaluates to false. if any function returns false, grep returns a non-empty array, which evaluates to true... nice.

Comment: @doubleDown: An easier way to think about it is that `grep` in scalar context (which `until` imposes) returns the number of elements of the list that satisfy the condition. In this case it counts the number of return values that aren't true, and we want to loop as long as that's zero (false).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to disable short-circuit evaluation, but you can evaluate each component at the beginning of the body of the loop, and break if any of the conditions is false.

```
while (1) {
    my $result1 = &proc1;
    my $result2 = &proc2;
    my $result3 = &proc3;
    last unless ($result1 && $result2 && $result3);
    ...
}
```